Calling c function from Rust with Hebrew characters
I have the following c library:
#include <cstdio>

extern "C" void print_name(const char *name) {
    printf("C name %s\n", name);
}

and I have the following Rust code which call it with Hebrew characters:
extern "C" {
    fn print_name(name: *const ::std::os::raw::c_char);
}

fn main() {
    let name = "עברית";
    println!("Rust name: {}", name);
    let c_name = std::ffi::CString::new(name).unwrap();
    unsafe {
        print_name(c_name.as_ptr());
    }
}

I compile it with:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl" /c /EHsc /MD /O2 /DNDEBUG lib.cpp
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\Hostx64\x64\lib" lib.obj /OUT:lib.lib
rustc main.rs -l lib -L .

And then run it from Powershell:
$ .\main.exe    
Rust name: עברית
C name ╫ó╫æ╫¿╫Ö╫¬

As you can see rust print it correctly, but the c function print it corrupted.
I would like to know how to fix it, and what's the theory behind fixing such encoding problems because I have this problem in another bigger project, and I faces it in many other projects.
Thanks!

If you are including <cstdio> then you are using C++, not C.

I don't use rust, but most likely rust is using UTF-8.  You'd use wprintf if you want multibyte characters, and you'd have to covnert from UTF-8 (assuming I'm right about rust using this encoding).

Fresh new rust thing: you can make C-string literals let name = c"עברית";

Well, you have to set the proper locale to achieve this in C/C++. If you are in windows you can do the following. Also note that there is the problem both how English and that language is written. English is written form the left and that language is written from the right. Since you showed printf so I assume you're only printing to terminal.
#include <cstdio>
#include <Windows.h>

extern "C" void print_name(const char *name);

extern "C" void print_name(const char *name) {
    printf("C name %s\n", name);
}

int main() { 
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    const char *name = "עברית";
    print_name(name);
    return 0;
}

output:
C name עברית

For Unix you maybe have to use #include <clocale> then use setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
but I can't verify that at the moment.

Nice to see you are recommending SetConsoleOutputCP() -- that has made the difference for me every time when facing issues like this.  setlocale() (as you said) should also be on OP's radar.  Good job.

Actually on Unix it should work without ever setting the locale. Most of the time at least. On Windows, SetConsoleOutputCP fiddles with the terminal settings. On Unix there is simply no comparable API. The terminal is either set up to work in UTF-8 (most of the time), or it is not, and you cannot change that from within your program. setlocale changes how byte strings are interpreted within the program, but printf doesn't need to interpret anything, it just sends raw bytes out.

Seems like the problem wasn't the encoder I used when called from rust but rather the encoding the terminal set to handle. What if I have this problem regradless of the terminal? I call C using Rust bindings (whiser-rs crate) and pass a path argument from rust, and the c function which expects char * arg return errors when passing path with hebrew characters?

check this link for c string literals in rust: https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2021/c-string-literals.html
or try passing raw bytes and then on your c side handle that.

I suggest asking a new question about handling paths. Get Rust out of the equation, just write a C++ program that doesn't work with a UTF-8 path string
